# Rails: I need to set a condition in a has_many that needs the self.id variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails: I need to set a condition in a has_many that needs the self.id variable

I need something like this:
has_many :posts, :conditions => "posts.hello_id = #{self.id}"
but self.id there it just doesnt work :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
class Bar
  has_many :foo, :conditions => "bar_id is NULL"
end

class Foo
  belongs_to :bar
end
```

Basically, you are providing SQL as the condition.

Another option, although I have never tried it myself, may be to use :finder_sql

```
has_many :posts, :finder_sql => 'select * from posts where hello_id = #{primary_key}'
```

Comment: I need something like this:
has_many :posts, :conditions => "posts.hello_id = #{self.id}"
but self.id there it just doesnt work :s

Comment: Posting your object model would help here. Is this statement in the Hello class? If so, that condition is not needed assuming that the Posts class has a belongs_to :hello statement.